# Filter fetched data in component

Tags: nuxt.js

I have a component, where I fetch my products array from the db. But I have to filter this products by specific categories. So I wrote a computed property to filter the products by category.

```js
computed: {
    filterNaturalSmall() {
      return this.products.data.filter((product) => {
        return product.categoryID === this.naturalID__small
      })
    },
  },
```

The problem is, when I enter the page I have to reload them to show my filtered products.
So, I get this error while entering the page for the first time.
`Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined`

The reason is, that the products aren't yet fully loaded when you enter.

I tried to write an if condition, but it will expect a returned value.

This is what I tried:

```js
computed: {
    filterNaturalSmall() {
      if (this.products.data) {
        this.products.data.filter((product) => {
          return product.categoryID === this.naturalID__small
        })
      }
    },
  },
```

Here is my simplified structure:

```js
<div v-for="naturalProd in filterNaturalSmall" :key="naturalProd._id">
   <p>{{ naturalProd.title }}</p>
</div>

export default {
  async fetch() {
    this.products = await this.$axios.$get('/api/all/products')
  },

  data() {
    return {
      products: [],
      naturalID__small: '5f7994a80c48da35967836be',
    }
  },

  computed: { ... },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could do it like this:

```js
computed: {
  filterNaturalSmall() {
    if (this.products.data) {
      this.products.data.filter((product) => {
        return product.categoryID === this.naturalID__small
      })
    }
    return false // this line is maybe not even needed
  },
},
```

and check in your template if it's available thanks to the new [`$fetchstate`](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/components-glossary/pages-fetch/#nuxt--212) helper

```html
...
<template v-if="$fetchState.pending"> <!-- not the root template here ! -->
  <div v-for="naturalProd in filterNaturalSmall" :key="natural._id">
     <p>{{ naturalProd.title }}</p>
  </div>
</template>
...
```

If you want more details on the various features of the `fetch` hook, you can read this blog post: https://nuxtjs.org/blog/understanding-how-fetch-works-in-nuxt-2-12/
And also the doc's official page on various ways to fetch data: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/data-fetching#the-fetch-hook

Comment: Thanks for answering! I reproduced it, but unfortunately this doesn't work in my case. It will return false. If I remove ``return false`` it will expect a returned value of course.

But I solved my problem in a different way.
I filter the products directly in the backend so that my frontend is also much clearer.

Comment: The computed property should re-evaluate if you do have data and `$fetchState.pending` should prevent any error. Still, it's always better to have it done on the backend yeah ! :D